# How to get to the correct documentation page?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose I'm trying to look up the documentation for `geometry_msgs`.

1. I start from https://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/ (which I perceive to be the root of the ros documentation)
2. Find the `geometry_msgs` folder (https://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/)
3. Open the `html` folder (https://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/)

However, that is just a dummy page.  The correct page I'm expecting is actually http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/index-msg.html

I couldn't quite figure out a way to get to that page from the documentation root and the only way of getting to the correct page is by googling.  It seems rather unintuitive that the correct documentation pages can only be found by google and not by navigating through the documentation itself.  This also makes finding less commonly linked documentation (which may not appear in google searches) more difficult.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362969/how-to-get-to-the-correct-documentation-page?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'd go to [wiki/geometry_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/geometry_msgs) and click on *Msg API* in the *Package Links* box in top right of the page.

That takes you directly to [docs.ros.org/noetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/index-msg.html](http://docs.ros.org/noetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/index-msg.html).

> I start from https://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/ (which I perceive to be the root of the ros documentation)

Personally I would consider the ROS wiki to be "the root of the ros documentation" for ROS 1.

For ROS 2, it would be the ROS Index.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-10-13**:
Thanks for the answer. Somewhat unrelated, but is there a reason why the Code API pages don't have a search bar?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-10-13**:
I wouldn't know.

Probably because it has not been enabled in the Doxygen config file template used by the doc generation infrastructure.

Perhaps if you open a PR this could be changed.